# Variable declaration performance on loops in Actionscript 3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, low-level

Despite all known blogs about this issue i always doubt some results and my personal tests shows that the well-said standard isn't the best.

Declaring variables inside the loop, to keep them close to its scope and make it faster to be reached by the method but allocating more memory or declaring outside the ***for*** scope to save memory allocation but increase processing to iterate in a distant instance.

My results shows that method B is faster(sometimes), i want to know the background around this.

results vary and im not a bit-brusher guru.

So what you guys think about it?

***Method A***

```
var object:Object = new Object();
var loop:int = 100000
for (var i:int = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
    object = new Object();
    object.foo = foo;
    object.bar = bar;
}
```

OR

***Method B***

```
var loop:int = 100000
for (var i:int = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
    var object:Object = new Object()
    object.foo = foo;
    object.bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the *actual* tests performed to see if they are valid, repeatable, and show what is being asserted. It is hard to get micro benchmarks correct (and just the above snippets are not adequate). There is *some*, albeit generally inconsequentail, argument for declaring variables inside nested-scopes (e.g. *nested functions*) and assigning a value to them to avoid searching through the [[scope]] chain, but that is a *different* case which requires a new [[scope]] to be observed.

Comment: Method B is faster because it has one fewer new's in it. It's the new statement that is taking the time here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tldr; they are semantically equivalent and perform identically.

There is only *one* variable called `object` in *both* cases presented. ActionScript, like JavaScript, "hoists" declarations. That is, `var` is *really just a function-scoped annotation*. This differs from C and Java where a new scope (and thus new variable) *would* have been created in the 2nd case.

There is no difference in AS, however. The engine *effectively treats* the 2nd code identical to the first. (That being said, I prefer to "keep the `var` close" to where it is used, while understanding it is not relevant to the scope and *has no bearing on performance*.)

See [Action Script 3.0: Variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html) and, the Scope section in particular:

> The scope of a variable is the area of your code where the variable can be accessed by a lexical reference... In ActionScript 3.0, **variables are always assigned the scope of the function or class in which they are declared.**

Happy coding.

Comment: I see in a way that the number of variable instantiations is equal to the number of loops since the ***var*** declaration is inside the loop lace

Comment: @ConradoSouza That is wrong. See the link. `var` **is not a declaration** (in the C/Java sense) in AS/JavaScript. It is a function-wide annotation. That is, it is "lifted" and applies to the function scope. (It is technically called a declaration; however, I making a point that it does not "declare" anything when that "line is run".)

Comment: @ConradoSouza This behavior can be seen as, outside the loop (even above the `var object` line!), `object` is accessible and will have the last value assigned.

Comment: understood, since i was arguing with C# Developers about this issue their perspective about this question was technically different from Actionscript3 Developers opinion. now that we understand the scope difference and the variable hoisting that happens in the compiler we can conclude that we can't compare method A and B performance in ActionScript but thinking about this on another environment like C/C++ i think method A would perform faster than B

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand this correctly: if you declare the same variable twice inside of a function, once before a for loop, and once within that for loop, there is absolutely no variable hiding, redundance, etc., except for the fact that you have var and possibly :<type> in two different spots.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 11):

AS3 compiler moves all the variable declarations to the top of the method which is called variable hoisting. And the minimum scope for a variable is a complete method. Your method B is equivalent of the following:

```
var loop:int = 100000;
var i:int;
var object:Object;
for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    object = new Object();
    object.foo = foo;
    object.bar = bar;
}
```

Note that it only moves the declaration up, not the associated assignment with this. This is the reason you can declare a variable after using it. For example try this code:

```
trace(a);
var a:int = 10;
trace(a);
```

This will compile. It's because this code is equivalent of:

```
var a:int;
trace(a);
a = 10;
trace(a);
```

This is also the reason that you will get a duplicate variable declaration warning with the following code:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < m; i++) {

}
for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++) { // i is already declared once

}
```

The concept of variable scope in AS3, JS is different from that of C, C++, Java etc.

Comment: Taskinoor, your answer is right as much pst one is, however, his answer contains more technical knowledge and it's what i was looking for, and probably anyone that comes to this question will be looking for it too.

Comment: @Conrado Souza, SO is about sharing knowledge and learning via helping each others. It is never about getting accepted or getting higher reputation, they are just by-products. I tried my best, that doesn't mean I provided the best answer.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine, though. Got my +1.

Comment: ahhh!  so THAT's why you can't declare again in a second loop.  thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 actually you can, what we saw here that its makes no difference at all :p, maybe just slightly increasing the compile time by forcing the compiler to adjust your code.

Comment: i guess it depends on the compiler settings?  whenever i've ever declared `i` twice in 2 separate loops of the same function the compiler complains.