# Warning: Duplicate variable definition

Tags: actionscript-3

If I have 2 `for` loops both declaring `var i`, then the second will produce a warning:

```
public function twoLoops(){
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    }

    for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) { // i is already declared once
    }
}
```

I understand the reason this happens, it's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743168/820750), but is there a way around it (except for declaring `i` at the beginning of the method)?

Comment: The other "solution" is to use `var j` instead of `var i` in the second loop :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes, but I also wanted to avoid this aswell. I just wondered if there was another way of doing it, maybe with a modifier keyword before `var`.

Comment: There is no solution other than dasblinkenlight's suggestion or your own. When AS functions are compiled, the variable declarations are automatically moved to the beginning of the method anyway so if you dont move the i declaration, the compiler will.

Comment: ..or just replace "var i:int" with "i" in second loop?

Comment: @LeeBurrows: This is a shame, I see that JavaScript has the `let` operator - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let, but apparently not as3

Comment: Peronally, i consider it an advantage that AS is 'strict' - leads to less bugs in the long run. Actually, you could turn off strict warnings in compiler settings but then you're not getting the benefits of error checking.

Comment: I've never needed the let operator in AS or JS, thought it existed in both (I stand corrected) but had it grouped with 'with' under 'keywords to avoid' - guess there could be benefits though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple - just don't declare it in the second loop:

```
public function twoLoops(){
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // i is already declared once
    }
}
```

This will work with no error - as your warning tells you, it's already defined, so you can use it again, setting it back to 0 to allow the loop to execute properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are so adamant in using the loop the way you are using, consider wrapping up in a function:

```
public  function twoLoops() {
    for (var  i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    }

    (function(){ 
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) { // i is already declared once       
        } 
    })();
}
```

Though it would not give any warning, I wonder what purpose would it really solve for you.